# Nethereum Wallet.GetAccount() giving EntryPointNotFound Exception

Tags: c#, .net, nethereum

EntryPointNotFound exception and code snippet

[image]

Comment: Please include code as text and any error message as text. It's impossible for us to debug an image.

Comment: i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was because of adding NBitcoin Package saperatly. As comes buitin with Nethereum Packages. I removed it from Packages and program ran fine.